# Is there any way to retrieve public event information from facebook graph api without oauth?

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I see a lot of similar questions, but none seems to really answer what I'm looking for.

I have a page with completely public information in the events page, and for some reason, when accessing it through graph api, I need an oauth access token. 
Is there any way around this?

the page's events are public - you can even access them without being logged in to facebook.

any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you got the event id you can just fetch the info with this url structure :

https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435 (331218348435 is the eventId in this case)

More info here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Yeah, but to get the list of events, I need the event url.. and that needs oauth for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need an access token to view event information, even if it's public. You can generate an "app token" - see here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

Then a `GET` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435?access_token=APP_TOKEN` should work fine - so long as the event is public.